# AttributeError: 'FigureWidgetResampler' object has no attribute 'gca'. How can I solve this problem in my code?

Tags: python

```
fig = CarModel.plot(CarPred,  figsize = (20, 10))
ax = fig.gca()
ax.set_title("Car Actual and Prediction Values", size = 22)
ax.set_xlabel("DateTime", size = 18)
ax.set_ylabel("Car Values", size = 18)
ax.tick_params(axis = "x", labelsize = 14)
ax.tick_params(axis = "y", labelsize = 14)`
```

I am not able to understand why I keep getting the error **(AttributeError: 'FigureWidgetResampler' object has no attribute 'gca'.)**

Comment: `FigureWidgetResampler` is a struct from `plotly-resampler`. You cannot use methods from `matplotlib.pyplot`.

Comment: Do you know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Yes. only use functions from `plotly`. Please refer to the [plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/) and the [plotly-resampler github page](https://github.com/predict-idlab/plotly-resampler#usage).